# How to change %26 to ampersand in the url?

Tags: php, html, url

I have simple login in my php

Where in i will input  password

> login.php

```
<form action="output.php" method="get">
    Enter your password:<input type="text" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value = "Login">
</form>
```

and it will give me an output

> output.php

```
<?php
$password = $_GET["password"];

if($password){
echo $password;
}

?>
```

but if i enter ampersand(**&**) on the textbox. the url change to **%26**

> http://localhost:8888/output.php?password=%26

how can i change it to ampersand(**&**)?

like

> http://localhost:8888/output.php?password=&

Thank you

Comment: This is url encoding default by browser. use  `urldecode($_GET('password'));` to get `&` in php

Comment: use encodeURIComponent()

Comment: You shouldn't, the encoding is correct and `$_GET["password"]` will contain `&`. And you should also not use GET for a password submit.

Comment: You don't want an ampersand in the URL since it is a special character (paramter separator): `password=&` would mean an empty password. You want to see an ampersand in your php-code, so you'll have to decode the URL-encoding. But since I don't know a thing about php I can't help you there.

Comment: @piet.t There's no need to decode it. Simply writing `echo $_GET['password'];` will give you `&`.

Comment: @VermaJr. That just confirms it: "I don't know a thing about php" ;)

Comment: @piet.t Oh man, okay :)

Comment: @piet.t You are somewhat correct tho, but some vars in PHP are decoded by default, `$_GET` being one of those. ([see here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php#refsect1-function.urldecode-notes))

Comment: Please don't send password with get, use post instead. `method="post"` and `$_POST['password']`